# Java - could not fetch clipboard data (midi) from CakeWalk

Tags: java, clipboard, midi

I am trying to get clipboard data (in windows) which were "copied" from CakeWalk midi editor. They are visible in clipboard viewers and could be pasted into other programs, but I could not get them in java program.

Following code snippet returns empty arrays when midi-data from cakewalk are in clipboard. Though when text from notepad is copied, for example, it returns up to 30 "flavors". What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;

public class TestClipboard {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c.getContents(TestClipboard.class).getTransferDataFlavors()));

        c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemSelection();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c.getContents(TestClipboard.class).getTransferDataFlavors()));
    }

}
```